# MongoDB C# Driver, Getting Elements By Projecting List in Model's attributes

Tags: c#, mongodb, projection

I have a collection of Objects which contains a property of type List
Where Luggage has the following structure:

```
    public class Luggage
    {
        public float MaxWeight { get; set; }
        public LuggageType Type { get; set; }
    }


    public class MyObject
    {
        public List<Luggage> Luggages{get;set;}

    }
```

Where LuggageType is an enum.
Given that I have a list of luggage types

`List<LuggageType> LuggageTypes`

How can I get every Object in my collection of Objects whose Luggages contain a luggage present in the LuggageTypes List.

I have tried several solutions but bellow is the one I beleive is the clossest to the solution.

Here is the filter I have created to retrieve what I wanted:

`Builders<MyObject>.Filter.AnyIn<LuggageType>(a => a.Luggages.Select(l => l.Type), annEntityaAttr.LuggageTypes);`

The problem is, MongoDB returns an error message stating that it couldn't compute the expression `a => a.Luggages.Select(l => l.Type)`
So I don't understand since it is Linq I though this should just work.
I guess I'll need some sort of projection, but I read the docs and didn't find a way to project a property of an element to be queried

Answer (score 0):

it can be done as follows. thing to note is you need to cast the enum values to an `IEnumerable<LuggageType>` so that we can use the `Contains()` extension.

code below uses **MongoDB.Entities** for brevity but the querying part is the same for the official driver. just replace `DB.Queryable<MyObject>()` with `collection.AsQueryable()`

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class MyObject : Entity
    {
        public List<Luggage> Luggages { get; set; }
    }

    public class Luggage
    {
        public float MaxWeight { get; set; }
        public LuggageType Type { get; set; }
    }

    public enum LuggageType
    {
        One = 1,
        Two = 2,
        Three = 3
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            (new MyObject
            {
                Luggages = new List<Luggage>
                {
                    new Luggage
                    {
                        MaxWeight = 12.345f,
                        Type = LuggageType.Three
                    },
                    new Luggage
                    {
                        MaxWeight = 12.345f,
                        Type = LuggageType.Two
                    }
                }
            }).Save();

            var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(LuggageType)).Cast<LuggageType>();

            var result = DB.Queryable<MyObject>()
                           .Where(o => o.Luggages.Any(l => enumValues.Contains(l.Type)))
                           .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```